# Javascript scrollIntoView only if in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a mockup (note that is uses interval as it was scrolling to new text line as video plays). I am using scrollIntoView with block: 'nearest'.

The problem is that since whole page has scroll, its still scrolls the page. I just want it to scroll to active text line in lines div (it doesnt have to be in view). Because if I am looking in "video" div, it will keep continue scrolling down (which is unwanted behavior).

```js
var text = document.querySelector('.text')


setInterval(function() {
  text.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'nearest'
  });

}, 3000)
```

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
}

.elem {
  position: relative;
}

.video {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.lines {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>


<div class="elem">
  <div class="video"></div>


  <div class="lines">
    <div>lorem ipsum dolir sit amet</div>
    <div>Vestibulum nulla justo</div>
    <div>Fusce egestas, est ut fringilla facilisis</div>
    <div>Maecenas eu erat condimentum </div>
    <div>Quisque risus</div>
    <div>fames ac turpis egestas</div>
    <div>lorem ipsum dolir sit amet</div>
    <div>Vestibulum nulla justo</div>
    <div class="text">Fusce egestas, est ut fringilla facilisis</div>
    <div>Maecenas eu erat condimentum </div>
    <div>Quisque risus</div>
    <div>fames ac turpis egestas</div>

  </div>


</div>

<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, `scrollIntoView()` isn't suitable for what you're trying to do here – it will scroll multiple view panes aggressively to try and get your element into view.

More appropriate would be `element.scrollTo(..)` on the parent element (`.lines` in this case). You need to do a little height arithmetic to center the element in the viewport but it is relatively straightforward:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('.text')

setInterval(function() {
  const parent       = text.parentElement;
  const parentHeight = parent.clientHeight;
  
  const textTop      = text.offsetTop - parent.offsetTop;
  const textMiddle   = textTop + text.offsetHeight / 2;

  parent.scrollTo({ top: textMiddle - parentHeight / 2, behavior: "smooth" });
}, 3000)
```

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
}

.elem {
  position: relative;
}

.video {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.lines {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:120px;
}

.text {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>


<div class="elem">
  <div class="video"></div>


  <div class="lines">
    <div>lorem ipsum dolir sit amet</div>
    <div>Vestibulum nulla justo</div>
    <div>Fusce egestas, est ut fringilla facilisis</div>
    <div>Maecenas eu erat condimentum </div>
    <div>Quisque risus</div>
    <div>fames ac turpis egestas</div>
    <div>lorem ipsum dolir sit amet</div>
    <div>Vestibulum nulla justo</div>
    <div class="text">Fusce egestas, est ut fringilla facilisis</div>
    <div>Maecenas eu erat condimentum </div>
    <div>Quisque risus</div>
    <div>fames ac turpis egestas</div>

  </div>


</div>

<div class="a"></div>
```